# How to insert matching values from one sheet into another in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in Excel:

- Sheet A contains medical equipment and the sensors they are using.
- Sheet B contains medical departments and the equipment they use.

I want to insert all the sensors of the medical equipment from Sheet A into Sheet B. How can I do this using a formula in Excel?

| Equipment | Unit | Model | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pump | Force | A | M1 |
| Pump | Magnetic | B | M2 |
| Pump | Pressure | C | M1 |
| Pulse Oximeter | Pressure | C | M3 |

| Department | Equipment |
| --- | --- |
| Surgery | Pump |
| Surgery | Pulse Oximeter |

The final table should look like this.

| Department | Equipment | Unit | Model | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Surgery | Pump | Force | A | M1 |
| Surgery | Pump | Magnetic | B | M2 |
| Surgery | Pump | Pressure | C | M1 |
| Surgery | Pulse Oximeter | Pressure | C | M3 |

I tried using this formula:

```
=INDEX(SheetA!B:B, MATCH(A2, SheetA!A:A, 0))
```

The problem here is, it only matches the first sensor value from Sheet A. So in this case, it only gets the "Force" sensor information.

Then I tried this formula:

```
=INDEX(SheetA!C:C, MATCH(B2, SheetA!A:A, 0)):INDEX(SheetA!C:C, MATCH(B2, SheetA!A:A, 1))
```

But I get an error for this formula. Is there any mistake that I don't see?

Comment: Why does final table **not** include a row for `Pulse Oximeter`?  Also, you write that your formula `didn't create empty rows`, but your final table doesn't show any empty rows. Explain this discrepancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be by using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Make your two tables `Tables`.

  - *I named them `Table_A` and `Table_B`, but you could use other names if you wish*
- Select some cell in one of the Data Tables
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in both tables
//Change table names to reflect your actual table names
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_B"]}[Content],
    Table_B = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Department", type text}, {"Equipment", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_A"]}[Content],
    Table_A = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source2), each {_, type text})),

//join them
//  then expand the nested table
    Final = Table.NestedJoin(Table_B,"Equipment", Table_A,"Equipment","Final",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Final" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Final, "Final", {"Unit", "Model", "Manufacturer"})
in
    #"Expanded Final"
```

***Table_A***
[image]

***Table_B***
[image]

***Final Result***
[image]